# Postgres - Using window function in grouped rows

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions

According to the Postgres Doc at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW it states

> If the query contains any window functions (...), these functions are evaluated after any grouping, aggregation, and HAVING filtering is performed. That is, if the query uses any aggregates, GROUP BY, or HAVING, then the rows seen by the window functions are the group rows instead of the original table rows from FROM/WHERE.

I didn't get the concept of " then the rows seen by the window functions are the group rows instead of the original table rows from FROM/WHERE". Allow me to use an example to explain my doubt:

Using this ready to run example below

```
with cte as ( 
  select 1 as primary_id, 1 as foreign_id, 10 as begins
  union
  select 2 as primary_id, 1 as foreign_id, 20 as begins
  union
  select 3 as primary_id, 1 as foreign_id, 30 as begins
  union
  select 4 as primary_id, 2 as foreign_id, 40 as begins
)
select foreign_id, count(*) over () as window_rows_count, count(*) as grouped_rows_count
from cte
group by foreign_id
```

You may notice that the result is

[image]

So if "the rows seen by the window functions are the group rows".. then ¿why `window_rows_count` is returning a different value from `grouped_rows_count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the window function from the query:

```
select foreign_id, count(*) as grouped_rows_count
from cte
group by foreign_id
```

the result, as expected is this:

```
> foreign_id | grouped_rows_count
> ---------: | -----------------:
>          1 |                  3
>          2 |                  1
```

and on this result, which is 2 rows, if you also apply the window function `count(*) over()`, it will return 2, because it counts all the rows of the resultset since the `over` clause is empty, without any `partition`.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the last comment on your post.
And for more analysis, you may process the following query :

```
with cte as ( 


select 1 as primary_id, 1 as foreign_id, 10 as begins
  union
  select 2 as primary_id, 1 as foreign_id, 20 as begins
  union
  select 3 as primary_id, 1 as foreign_id, 30 as begins
  union
  select 4 as primary_id, 2 as foreign_id, 40 as begins
)
select foreign_id, count(*) over (PARTITION BY foreign_id) as window_rows_count, count(*) as grouped_rows_count
from cte
group by foreign_id ;
```

You'll see this time that you are getting 1 row for each foreign id.
Checkout the documentation on postgres at this url :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html

The window function is applied to the whole set obtained by the former query.